# Health Device Profile in Windows

Tags: bluetooth

I am going to have a project that can get data from devices that support **Health Device Profile(HDP)** in **Windows**.

I find **Bluez** but it is only available in **Linux**. Is there any **alternative in Windows**? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple suppliers of Bluetooth stack for desktop Windows.  The only one that I know supports HDP directly is Toshiba (though I've no experience with it).  So, instead once can add the HDP support outside of the stack software.  However, HDP[1] uses the L2CAP protocol which is lower level that RFCOMM protocol that most apps use, and unfortunately Microsoft's Bluetooth stack does not provide a user-level L2CAP API.  I started work on a driver to allow user-mode access to the kernel-level API (provided by MSFT in Vista and later) but never finished it.  For the other main stacks BlueSoleil doesn't provide a L2CAP API, but Widcomm does.

[1] http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20Profiles%20and%2032feet.NET.html#_Toc266869895

Comment: Thx for your response.
Do u mean I can use Widcomm SDK to implement the software?
But I can hardly find relevant example of connecting HDP device using Widcomm SDK by searching Widcomm and HDP

Comment: There is no direct support for HDP in Widcomm.  You'd need to read all the HDP profile specifications from the Bluetooth SIG and implement all of that as well as the application of HDP you need. :-(